# will running laptop in hibernation mode cause problems

Tags: windows-8, hardware-failure, hibernate

I have DELL Inspiron 14r touch laptop with i5 processor, 2GB graphics card, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot.

Now, my question is more hardware specific, I want to know most of the time my computer is turned on. And the time when I don't use my computer I turn it into hibernation mode. So, basically my system is almost always on or else in hibernation mode, except at night.

So, will this cause any adverse effect on my hardware? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Hibernation just means that your RAM's content is written to the hard drive and later read from there instead of booting.

What you could face is data loss. Just make sure that you always resume from the operating system from which you hibernated. There can be strange effects if one of the operating systems finds different stuff on the disk than it was seeing there just before hibernation.

Comment: beat me! have an up

Answer (score 1):

Hibernation mode is when the OS saves it's running state to disk and powers down. To say your system is "on" when hibernating is misleading. The system is paused, with every component powered off except the CMOS.

You will not cause any damage to hardware by using hibernation mode.